# installing old versions of cv2 using pip

Tags: pip, opencv, sift, python

i've been trying to download older versions of cv2 as an easy way to get around not being able to use SIFT.
I've tried the following:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```

however I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17 (from versions: 3.4.8.29, 3.4.9.31, 3.4.9.33, 4.1.2.30, 4.2.0.32, 4.2.0.34)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```

All the advice I've seen on the site so far tells me to either download these older versions of opencv or to build it myself (which seems like an absolute nightmare)
Anyone have any suggestions on how to install these older versions of cv2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[opencv-contrib-python 3.4.2.17](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/3.4.2.17/#files) provides wheels for Pythons up to 3.7. Probably you use Python 3.8.

Use Python 3.7 (or lower). Or compile from sources for 3.8.